# How to change the html file location in Wicket 6.0

Tags: html, wicket-1.6

How to change the html file location in Wicket 6.0.

Thanks,
Syam.

Answer (score 2):

Just add the following line to the init()-method of your Application class (Wicket 6):

```
getResourceSettings().getResourceFinders().
    add(new WebApplicationPath(getServletContext(), "/"));
```

Wicket will then look for the html files in the main folder of your web archive (additionally to the default location in the classpath). However, the HTML file must still be in a folder that corresponds to the package of the Wicket Page class (i.e. if the class name is foo.bar.HomePage, the HTML file must be in a folder foo/bar/HomePage.html with the above setting.

Comment: Did you get it to work? I created an example application at https://github.com/thombergs/wicket-markuploading-example if you're interested.